# Eval Parse unexpected symbol when input contains a space

Tags: r, shiny

I am building a shiny app where the user can dynamically change the colour of linecharts according to his preference. In order to do that I am using the following function for generating a linechart:

```
create_line<-function(data,filter,x,y,colour,shape,size,alpha){

cols <- paste0("c(", paste0("input$col", sort(filter), collapse = ", "), ")")
cols <- eval(rlang::parse_expr(cols))
req(length(cols) == length(filter))  

data %>%   
ggplot(aes(x=x,y=y,colour=colour))+
geom_point(shape=shape,size=size,alpha=alpha)+ geom_line()+
generate_theme()+
scale_colour_manual(values = cols)}

output$plot1 <- renderPlotly({
  create_line(data(),                                    # data 
                   input$producer,                       # filter   
                   data()$date,                          # x-axis
                   data()$total,                         # y-axis
                   data()$content_producer,              # colour
                   21, 0.8, 0.8)})                       # shape,size,alpha
```

Whereby data() is a reactive with data that user can input like the date range and the content_proucer. The user can change the colour of the input(filter in this case) and it works just fine when the input does not contain a space. For example, if the input would be 'Main Road' it doesn't work(and gives the Unexpected symbol error), but if it is 'MainRoad' it works. Is there a way to make this work without actually removing the space of the input?

Comment: Try using backticks: `\`Main Road\``. Does this work?

Comment: Hi Starja, where would you suggest putting it in the code above? I tried putting it in the input$col, collapse, and closing bracket in the 

cols <- paste0("c(", paste0("input$col", sort(filter), collapse = ", "), ")")

but it still doesn't work :(

Comment: To be honest, I'm not sure what you want to do. The `filter` variable is a name that contains a space? Then you don't need to change anything in your function, but you have to make sure that the value passed to `filter` contains backticks

Comment: How do you call `create_line` function ?

Comment: Hi Ronak, I edited my question and added the call to create_line inside the renderPlotly in the server part.